# Salesforce Java connection works for Sandbox but not for production

Tags: salesforce

I built a Java application which connects to Salesforce to access data. However, this connection only works for the sandbox account and not when I pass the production accounts credentials.

I set up the connection in the following manner,

```
Connector.newConnection(config)
```

The error I get is as follows,

> [LoginFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='INVALID_LOGIN'
>   exceptionMessage='Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.'
>   extendedErrorDetails='{[0]}']]

Does anyone know how to solve this? Is there some sort of dependency I am forgetting?

Comment: can you include the connection information blurring any personal info? My guess is you're attempting to login through the test.salesforce.com endpoint and not the login.salesforce.com endpoint

Comment: I think that maybe the issue. Maybe I've added the wrong .jar or something like that. I found out that Connection class is that is used has it's endpoint variable as test.salesforce.com.

Comment: Typically I think that information should be in your config object you're passing. I could be wrong, I have not used the java sdk.

Comment: Actually no. Config object was correct. However, in the salesforce-partner.jar that I used the endpoint is hardcoded as test.salesforce.com. It should be noted that when changing to the production environment this jar should be generated newly from the partner.wsdl provided by the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the partner.jar that was used. This has the endpoint hardcoded as test.salesforce.com. Therefore would never work in the production environment as the log in wouldn't even go to the correct URL.

Therefore, you should always remember to generate the partner.jar from the partner.wsdl provided by the production environment and add it. The endpoint here is hardcoded as login.salesforce.com.